# Is it possible to damage a DC motor by not fully charging the battery power supply?

Tags: motor, dc

I bought three small motors which each use a high capacity rechargeable Li-ion battery as a power source.  I did not charge any of the batteries before using them.  Two worked, but the third did not.

I then charged all three batteries and the third motor still did not work.

The motor has a warranty.  When I asked for a replacement the supplier said I damaged the motor since I used it without charging the battery first.  I don't understand how this would damage the motor.  Does anyone know or is the supplier trying to avoid replacing the motor?

Since it is a motor kit used for roller shades I do not have any specifications on the motor other than:

- Protection Class: IP44
- Rated RPM: 26
- Rated Torque: 9.74in.lb (1.1N.M),

Comment: Not impossible. Compare stall current with operating current. If you supply slightly less than stall current, the motor won't start. and will remain in the stalled condition consuming whatever current you supply, dissipating all that power as heat.

Answer (score 4):

If the motors fail to turn, they can heat up, but this is a State of Charge that any battery, previously charged, will/may experience with power charger failure. The design must protect both the motors and battery from stalling and excess current or heat or low voltage. This is normal practice.  A stalled motor with normal 2/3 shipping charge means a mechanical fault if there was any sound or an electrical faulty connection or fault, if no sign of power.

He is not honouring your expectation of quality and performance if this product has no protection from a low battery.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to damage a DC Motor by not fully charging the battery power supply?

Is it possible? Yes. Is that what happened? I don't know.

A motor which is stalled draws a large amount of current. Enough to damage the motor if it occurs for too long. A motor with a load, and insufficient voltage to get it going, *could* draw too little current to start, but too much current to survive.

Did the motor smell when you first tried to start it? That would be a bad sign. Can you check the winding resistance(s) and compare the value(s) with the know good motors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The motor is in a sealed housing so I can't access it without voiding the warranty (which might be useless, but at this point I am still pressing my case). I first tried the motor with no load, there was no response from the motor, ie no smells, beeps or motor movement.